# Changing MacOS theme from terminal

Tags: macos, automation

I have the following problem - in the office I want my mac to be as light theme as we have too much light and it's just impossible to use Dark theme.
When i am home - I want to use Dark theme as it's much darker environment.

BUT, I don't want everytime to configure it manually.

I am looking for a way to change the macos theme programmably, with terminal command or some script, so I will be able to create a scheduled task which will change the theme based on the IP address of the computer.

unfortunately I didn't find a way to change the theme not from the computer Setting, anyone have an idea how can I implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should answer your question: [How to set dark mode appearance to auto in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391686/how-to-set-dark-mode-appearance-to-auto-in-terminal)

Set appearance to dark:

```
defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool true
```

Set appearance to auto:

```
defaults write -g AppleInterfaceStyleSwitchesAutomatically -bool true
```